# Nested Functions Visual representation ("flowcharts")

Tags: c, uml, modeling, flowchart

I **have** to do some visual representation of C-code. There are some nested function in it and one or two callback functions.

How can I best show the functionality? Can the control symbol help?

e.g.

```
fooA(){
 fooB();
 fooC();
}
```

When I do `A --> B --> C` it feels wrong.

`A --> B --> A --> C` is even more wrong.

Maybe

```
A --> B
  -----> C
```

But when I add another function to `fooB()` it gets messy...

```
fooB{
 fooD();
}
```

`A --> B --> D --> C` misses the point...

At the moment the best way seems to do it in a 2Dimensional way. But it's not beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get the point of this (beautiful?), but if you want to show it in UML (it is so tagged), you have to basic options: **activities** and **sequence diagrams**.

Answer (score 1):

If you **have** to create a visual representation of the code then some ASCII text art is probably not what you are expected to do. This technique is out of the mainstream for some 10 or more years.

Check following links for inspiration:

- http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html
- http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Support/CodeRocketDesigner/Screenshots
- http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm
- http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/activityDiagram.htm

(Or Google for **images** of `flow chart`, `UML sequence diagram`, `UML activity diagram` as @Aleks suggests)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is a programming question, but the way I typically represent something like this is with a tree.

for your examples above, I'd have

```
fooA
 |--->fooB
 |     |--->fooD
 |--->fooC
```

Of course, the answer also depends upon what it is that you're trying to show? Because fooD may call fooC as well, which may or may not become messy to you:

```
fooA
 |--->fooB
 |     |--->fooD
 |           |--->fooC
 |--->fooC
```

You now have fooC listed twice in your tree, but you also clearly discriminate from the fooC that's called by fooD and the one that's called by fooA.

You'll also need to be wary of recursion. What if fooB can call fooA?

```
fooA
 |--->fooB
 |     |--->fooA
 |     |--->fooD
 |           |--->fooC
 |--->fooC
```